# getting whole Json String in Aerospike (inserted from java Client ) from aql

Tags: aerospike

I've inserted Json string in a Aerospike Bin through java client and retrieved it through java that's good and working fine.

Now I am interested to see my Json string in aql bin, But i could see only half of the string like

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| abcList
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| "[{"abc":false,"abc":"7871248","abc":1423114706392,"abc":1423114706392,"abc":5,"abc":"12345","abc":0,"originalCartItemSequenceNumber":0,"abc":false,"abc":"","sourceCustomerId":nu | "d016cf2a-cf8f-435a-b9d5-de486da4737b" |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)

Here if you observe after some point I am getting only dots . So how could I get all the result is there any Configuration changes I have to do ?

Please some one help me

Answer (score 6):

In aql: `set output json` should show you the entire result.
`set output table` will revert to the default.

Answer (score 2):

aql only prints upto 256 characters in a cell. This is make sure that we do not fill up the entire screen with a large string. Unfortunately, its a hard coded limit and cannot be configured.

aql is only meant for debugging/diagnostic purposes. Its not meant for in-production use. The above limit is not unreasonable for this perspective.